# MVVM on Winforms: disabled buttons can be hovered (using async/await)

Tags: c#, winforms, mvvm, async-await

Since I'm not familiar with WPF I wanted to try using the MVVM pattern in Winforms. I have a form that on the click of a button starts an async method that retrieves msgs via API.

The operation is running in my view model where are also the properties that control some UI behaviour. The view model implements INotifyOnPropertyChanged via Fody Weaver Property Changed and has a BindingSource that receives the view model itself as DataSource.

```
BindingSource bsViewModel = new BindingSource();
bsViewModel.DataSource = this; // this being the view model the BindingSource lives in
```

The VM properties are bound to the properties of the controls with DataBinding.Add() This is working fine except with this glitch. The button text is updated correctly but the colouring of the buttons only when I hover the mouse over them (or call Refresh(); in the UserControl where these buttons are placed).

A colleague is using the same technique with BindingSource, MVVM in WinForms but a BackgroundWorker instead of async await. He doesn't have that problem. His buttons disable properly and don't show the hover effect when disabled.

What could be the cause for this half disabled button?

[image: disabled buttons have hover effect]

Comment: I also have implemented MVVM in Winforms without the issues you're having... You could post a small code example so we can reproduce you're problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple ReactiveUI sample:

1.- Create a new Winforms project (.net 4.5)

2.- Add reactiveui-winforms nuget package (7.4.0)

3.- Add a new class called "MainViewModel" and add this references:

```
using System;
using System.Reactive;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ReactiveUI;
```

4.- This is the class code:

```
public class MainViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    private bool canExecute;
    private string textButton;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        this.CanExecute = true;
        this.TextButton = "Press me"
        // the command creation, this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.CanExecute) is an observable that will change the enabled/disabled command when CanExecute changes
        this.AsyncProcess = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(AsyncProcessImpl, this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.CanExecute));
    }

    public bool CanExecute
    {
        get { return this.canExecute; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref this.canExecute, value); }
    }

   public string TextButton
   {
        get { return textButton; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref textButton, value); }
   }

    public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> AsyncProcess { get; } 

    private async Task AsyncProcessImpl()
    {
        // changing CanExecute to false will disable the button
        this.CanExecute = false;
        this.TextButton = "Wait..."
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)); // just for testing
        // CanExecute back to true, the button will be enabled
        this.CanExecute = true;
        this.TextButton = "Press me";
    }
}
```

5.- Open the Form1 form and add a button named "btnStart".

6.- Open the Form1 code behind and add reference to ReactiveUI:

```
using ReactiveUI;
```

7.- Change the class to:

```
public partial class Form1: Form, IViewFor<MainViewModel>
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // ViewModel initialization
        this.ViewModel = new MainViewModel();

        // binding creation when the form is activated
        this.WhenActivated(dispose => {
            // the command binding will be disposed when the form is deactivated, no memory leaks
            dispose(this.BindCommand(this.ViewModel, x => x.AsyncProcess, x => x.btnStart));
            dispose(this.OneWayBind(this.ViewModel, x => x.TextButton, x => x.btnStart.Text);
        });
    }

    public MainViewModel ViewModel { get;  set; }

    object IViewFor.ViewModel
    {
        get { return this.ViewModel; }
        set { this.ViewModel = value as MainViewModel; }
    }
}
```

8.- Run the application

EDIT: If you want to change which event will rise the command, just add the last parameter in the BindCommand method:

```
dispose(this.BindCommand(this.ViewModel, x => x.AsyncProcess, x => x.btnStart, "TheEventNameYouWant"));
```

You can bind a command to any control with a Disable property, just use the name of the event that will raise the command.

Comment: This works nicely. Thanks for the extensive example. But I've never worked with observables so if you have any more links to samples that would be helpful!

Comment: I would like to know how I can bind to the button text for example. It appears that the `BindCommand` automatically raises the Click event and changes the Enabled property of the button. Can I even say which property and events are bound?

Comment: Check the edit. Observables are great, just think in IEnumerable (including linq) like a pull collection, and IObservable like a push collection.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in WinForms itself. It just doesn't lend itself die the MVVM pattern which I was aware of but wanted to give it a shot anyway.

I tried my async method with using the background worker. The issue with the buttons was the same. It only happens if you change the view model properties from within the async method / from a different thread.

Another thing I noticed is that visibility can't be controlled at all using view model properties and data binding. Enabled properties only work if you set then by way of progress reporting. It's a pitty but I want to learn WPF anyway...

**Update:** the only workaround I found outside of ReactiveUI is working with `IProgress<Action>`. In the async method I change the properties of my ViewModel within the `progress.Report(new Action() => { ... })` and the databindings do the rest. Also INotifyPropertyChanged needs to be implemented in the ViewModel (nuget PropertyChanged.Fody will help here).

Comment: You can do MVVM perfectly in Winforms, probably your implementation is not good enough. Try ReactiveUI, my Winforms projects using MVVM with ReactiveUI are working fine. I can bind Enabled and Visible properties without issues.

Comment: And you are updating those properties out of an async method, yes?

Comment: async and sync methods.

Comment: Ok, then rather down voting my answer which is actually true for WinForms without ReactiveUI could you provide your own answer with working code examples to back up your claims! I'd be intrigued to use ReactiveUI but their website doesn't seem to be complete when it comes to WinForms.

Comment: I don't down voted you ;) I'll try to upload an example to github.

Comment: Sorry, then someone did around the same time you commented. Looking forward to your link!